# Is there a way to use shell commands from within the code in Replit?

Tags: python, discord, replit

I've been working on a program for a program for running a Discord bot using Replit as the host.
Recently, my bot has been getting rate limited by Discord. I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67395660/replit-discord-bot-blocked-from-discord) that the cause of this is most likely due to Replit sharing an IP address between my bot and other users' bots.

As a temporary fix, I've been rebooting my Replit by typing "kill 1" into the shell console to restart the bot on different IP addresses. However, this process has been cumbersome and problematic since I want to have my bot running 24/7. Another user in the post linked above suggested that it was possible to write a script that detects and executes the kill 1 command every time the bot is banned.
I was curious if this is possible and if it is what an example script may look like. For reference, my bot is coded in Python. Thanks for any help.

...

The question deemed a duplicate to mine does not answer my question nor does it help me to understand how I can create my own code to fix this problem.

My aim is to: 1. Detect when the bot has been rate limited 2. Kill the program 3. Have the program automatically restart on a new IP address without having to manually press the "Run" button.

I am not sure if there is a way to use `os.kill()` to accomplish all of these tasks although if it can I would like help understanding how.

My problem is the same outline in [the post  I referred to earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67395660/replit-discord-bot-blocked-from-discord) if that helps.

```
if <program detects ban>
   //kill program
   //restart Replit
```

[image]

Comment: `kill` just calls the same thing Python calls `os.kill()`. You don't need the shell command at all; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill

Comment: If you in fact have a replit-specific problem, _show us a reproducer_ that demonstrates how/why the normal approach doesn't work there, and exactly what behavior you get instead; [mre] guidelines demonstrate what we're looking for, roughly.

Comment: I don't see how the duplicate _doesn't_ solve your problem. `import os`, then `os.kill(signal.SIGTERM, 1)` and you've got an operation identical to `kill 1`, which is what you asked how to do. If you're asking about something like how to write `<program detects ban>`, you need to be explicit about that, but it's probably too broad to be on-topic here. We only permit _narrow, specific_ problems; we won't write code to do everything that's part of "your aim" for you -- instead, you need to ask about a _very particular_ place you got stuck when writing your program yourself.

Comment: Trying to run `kill 1`, for example, is specific/particular enough to be on-topic, but it's _also_ a duplicate of the preexisting knowledge base entry linked. If you have another specific problem... ask it, but be clear about _specifically_ what you're asking.

Comment: This question was closed because it is difficult to understand what you are asking. I would suggest provide more detail or clarity to the question and it might be voted to be re-opened.